# Celery subqueues (implementing sequential message delivery)

Tags: python, redis, celery, messaging, amqp

I'm trying to implement a chatbot system, and I need to have my celery tasks processed sequentially per user. That means each user needs to have their messages sent as FIFO, but the users need to be processed randomly or in round-robin.

I've been reading about task chains, groups and trees, but all of these celery features seem to require providing all tasks at once, whereas I need to add tasks dynamically.

My reasoning was to have a dedicated queue per user, and enable concurrency on the queues. That way I can assure the delivery order and avoid one user blocking the rest of the chats.

Is there a way I can route tasks in Celery so I get the desired behavior? Ideally, I'd set up a worker to process the `messages` queue, and then route tasks to `messages.contact.<contact_id>` or the like.

There's no explicit mention to this behavior in the docs. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: I'm stuck using celery, since I'm working over an existing system, trying to replace a complex and fragile synchronization mechanism. Looking to refactor this following best practices!

Comment: You can use ```pubsub``` module or something like that. with Celery I don't think you can achieve this 100%.

Comment: @ManojJadhav do you mean https://github.com/Mulugruntz/celery-pubsub ? It's odd this can't be accomplished with Celery alone, looks like a pretty basic use case to me. Maybe there's a piece I'm missing?